# aiohttp rate limiting requests with unreliable internet

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am downloading content from a website with a *very* strict rate limit. If I exceed 10 req/sec, I am banned for 10 minutes. I have been using the following code to rate limit AIOHTTP:

```py
import time

class RateLimitedClientSession:
    """Rate Limited Client.
    Attributes:
        client (aiohttp.ClientSession): A client to call
        rate_limit (int): Maximum number of requests per second to make
    https://quentin.pradet.me/blog/how-do-you-rate-limit-calls-with-aiohttp.html
    """

    def __init__(self, client, rate_limit):
        self.client = client
        self.rate_limit = rate_limit
        self.max_tokens = rate_limit
        self.tokens = self.max_tokens
        self.updated_at = time.monotonic()
        self.start = time.monotonic()

    async def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Wrapper for ``client.get`` that first waits for a token."""
        await self.wait_for_token()
        return self.client.get(*args, **kwargs)

    async def wait_for_token(self):
        """Sleeps until a new token is added."""
        while self.tokens < 1:
            self.add_new_tokens()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.03) # Arbitrary delay, must be small though.
        self.tokens -= 1

    def add_new_tokens(self):
        """Adds a new token if time elapsed is greater than minimum time."""
        now = time.monotonic()
        time_since_update = now - self.updated_at
        new_tokens = time_since_update * self.rate_limit
        if self.tokens + new_tokens >= 1:
            self.tokens = min(self.tokens + new_tokens, self.max_tokens)
            self.updated_at = now
```

Then I can use it as such:

```py
from aiohttp import ClientSession, TCPConnector

limit = 9 # 9 requests per second
inputs = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', ...]
conn = TCPConnector(limit=limit)
raw_client = ClientSession(connector=conn, headers={'Connection': 'keep-alive'})
async with raw_client:
    session = RateLimitedClientSession(raw_client, limit)
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(download_link(link, session)) for link in inputs]
    for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        await task

async def download_link(link, session):
    async with await session.get(link) as resp:
        data = await resp.read()
        # Then write data to a file
```

My issue is that the code will work correctly for a random amount of times, usually between 100 and 2000. Then, it exits due to hitting the rate limit. I suspect this has to do with the latency of my internet.

For example, imagine a 3 request/second limit.

```
SECOND 1:
 + REQ 1
 + REQ 2
 + REQ 3

SECOND 2:
 + REQ 4
 + REQ 5
 + REQ 6
```

With a little bit of lag, this might look like

```
SECOND 1:
 + REQ 1
 + REQ 2

SECOND 2:
+ REQ 3 - rolled over from previous second due to internet speed
+ REQ 4
+ REQ 5
+ REQ 6
```

Which then triggers the rate limit.

**What can I do to minimize the chance of this happening?**

- I have already tried lowering the rate limit, and it does work for a longer period of time but still eventually hits the rate limit.
- I have also tried firing each request 1/10 a second apart, but this still triggers the rate limit (perhaps for unrelated reasons?).

Comment: Sounds like the banning is less than reliable. Must admit if I wanted to ensure someone couldn’t too easily scrape too much off my website then making the banning unpredictable might not be uninteresting. You’ll have to balance the rate you use with the cost of being banned for 10 minutes, that’s 6000 requests. If over an hour you could make 10 requests/s that would be (ideally) 36000 requests. With the ban hit once you could maybe make 30000 requests, i.e. 5/6 of the max. So if you slowed down the rate from 10/s to 5/6 of 10/s then you aren’t losing out - that’s 50/6=just over 8/s. Tried 8?

Comment: @barny I have, but it still eventually hits the rate limit, and I am looking for some sort of code solution that is more reliable than lowering it. Do you think the issue is latency here, or could it be something in my code or that they have what you said (a unreliable rate limit)?

Comment: Using a reliable internet connection would eliminate one of the variables. If the issue were latency, could you always delay the next request until the previous 10 have completed and one second has passed since the 10th previous completed - the point being to use the completion time to ensure that the latency is (should not be) not causing the limit to trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided that the best solution was to batch the requests into groups, and await the missing time. I no longer use a rate-limiting wrapper around AIOHTTP.

```py
async def download_link(link, session):
    async with await session.get(link) as resp:
        data = await resp.read()
        # Then write data to a file


def batch(iterable, n):
    l = len(iterable)
    for ndx in range(0, l, n):
        yield iterable[ndx:min(ndx + n, l)]

rate_limit = 10
conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=rate_limit)
client = aiohttp.ClientSession(
    connector=conn, headers={'Connection': 'keep-alive'}, raise_for_status=True)

async with client:
    for group in batch(inputs, rate_limit):
        start = time.monotonic()
        tasks = [download_link(link, client) for link in group]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks) # If results are needed they can be assigned here
        execution_time = time.monotonic() - start
        # If execution time > 1, requests are essentially wasted, but a small price to pay
        await asyncio.sleep(max(0, 1 - execution_time))
```